# How to write Schrodinger equation!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, schroedinger-equation

Quantum mechanics: Suppose that there is a particle with orbital angular momentum |L|. But if the particle also has spin quantity |S| the question is: How do I reflect this into Schrodinger equation? I do know how Schrodinger equation becomes for each case - when a particle has particular orbital angular momentum and when a particle has some spin, especially when both occur.

Comment: Your question makes little sense in the context of quantum mechanics. Particles don't follow paths, specifically not circles and spin in an intrinsic property, not one of motion.

Comment: @A.O.Tell Modified the question.

Comment: Just adding spin means you attach a tensor factor space containing the spin representation to the particle space. The schroedinger equation doesn't change unless you add an interaction term that incorporates spin. Which term that is depends on your actual physical model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Schroedinger equation does not describe spin. If you need to describe spin as well, you should use the Pauli equation or the Dirac equation (for spin 1/2).

Comment: so angular momentum can be reflected, but spin can't?

Comment: That's right, unless you use some unusual definition of the Schroedinger equation.

Comment: What is understood by *Schrödinger equation* here and how to interpret *should*?

Comment: Schrödinger equation is understood as the second equation in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation , marked "Time-dependent Schrödinger equation (single non-relativistic particle)". If you understand it as the first equation there (marked "Time-dependent Schrödinger equation (general)"), then you include, e.g., the Dirac equation there and what not. I cannot add anything to dictionary definitions of "should".

Comment: This answer is **incorrect**. The term _Schrödinger's equation_ refers to any equation of the form $i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\Psi\rangle =\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$, or coordinate representations of it. For a single spinless nonrelativistic particle, this reduces to the form $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)+V(\mathbf{x},t)\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ you quote from Wikipedia. In other cases it can be quite different; one example of this is the [Pauli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation), also known as the Schrödinger-Pauli equation

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: i respectfully disagree. I use a standard and legitimate definition of the Schroedinger equation (see, e.g., http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SchroedingerEquation.html ), furthermore, it is clear from my answer what definition I use. According to your definition, the Dirac equation is a special case of the Schroedinger equation. You can use such a definition, but that does not mean that I cannot use mine.

Comment: That much is correct, but the usual convention is the more general one, and it is definitely not OK to dismiss equations as not being Schrödinger's equation because they do not conform to some narrow definition. And yes, Dirac's equation is a Schrödinger equation.

Comment: (Specifically, it can be constructed as the essentially unique Lorentz invariant Schrödinger equation (which in particular means linear in $p$) whose solutions are also solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation. For details see, for example, Messiah's derivation.)

Comment: @akhmeteli: I'm abit confused by your definition of Schrödinger Eqn. As I understand, according to you $H=\hbar/2\sigma_i$ in the first eqn in Emilios's comment is *not* a Schrödinger Eqn (I'm sorry for such a poor choice of words but I don't know how I should express the issue we are discussing). Is that what you are implying?

Comment: @gonenc: I gave the references for the definition I use, and your (very strange) Hamiltonian does not fall under that definition. If you want to use Emilio Pisanty's definition, it's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can talk about spin and spin interactions with the standard Schrodinger.  Start with [spin orbit coupling or LS Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling)

Next see the Zeeman effect, and especially [Paschen Bach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%E2%80%93Back_effect#Strong_field_.28Paschen-Back_effect.29)

You need perturbation theory to pick up on spin effects given standard Schrodinger model of the atom as seen [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%E2%80%93Back_effect#Strong_field_.28Paschen-Back_effect.29):

> First order perturbation theory with these fine-structure corrections yields the following formula for the Hydrogen atom in the Paschen-Back limit:[2]